# Scroll to a FormControl Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm validating a large form of Angular, 
I have been trying to scroll to the first invalid `FormControl` in that form without success, the only answer that I find is find the reference of the `nativeElement` and apply a `scrollTo` from native Javascript,

Does anyone have another more clean solution for this?

Comment: seems like angular not provide that thing , as angular is framewrok which deals with presentation of data ...

Comment: Can you share what you have found?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it from the template directly, you may use somthing like this:

```
<div #top>
   very long content
   ...
</div
<button (click)="top.scrollIntoView()">Submit</button>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qa2x7e)**

Comment: The FormControl doesn't have an ID to scroll to